# TWebBrowser Cannot Open Blogspot Website

Tags: delphi, delphi-xe2, twebbrowser

I'm using Delphi XE2 in Windows 7 64 bit, I put TWebBrowser component in a Form. I navigate it to a blogspot website, e.g:

```
Webbrowser1.Navigate('http://maniacpcgame.blogspot.com');
```

it shows JavaScript Error (HTML Parsing Error), then I turn Silent properties to True as follow:

```
Webbrowser1.Silent := true;
Webbrowser1.Navigate('http://maniacpcgame.blogspot.com');
```

But the browser cannot open the page properly (only show background image). I tried other blogspot websites and got same problem. Any solution to display blogspot website correctly in TWebBrowser?

Comment: Cannot reproduce with Delphi 2009 on Windows 7 64-bit, IE 9.0.8112.16421. Yes, I got a JavaScript error during loading, but I've seen the page with its content (not only background image). Anyway, from the `TWebBrowser` point of view, there not much you can do with it. You can ignore the errors and get unexpected behavior on the page, or you can fix those errors on your site.

Comment: ^^^+1 cant reproduce either - Delphi XE on windows 7 64-bit, same IE version

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Twebbrowser uses IEFRAME

IEFRAME depends on the version of internet explorer you are running on that computer
You can deploy IEFRAME.DLL (in c:windows/system32 )with your application so you can be sure the same version is used everywhere so you wont get inconsistencies between computers.

However newer ones wont work on XP and there are some directx requirements.

A good alternative is
Delphi Embed chromium, it makes your deployed application a lot bigger (+-15MB) but you can be very sure it works everywhere and always (windows 8 to XP) and it will always produce the same page
Also if you have to manipulate the DOM or insert javascript (to communicate with the page)
this will be easier and will work more consistently.

Here is a link for the latest version: 
https://code.google.com/p/dcef3/

Comment: The latest version of Chromium wrapper for Delphi is [`DCEF 3`](https://code.google.com/p/dcef3/). And, I wouldn't say DOM manipulation is easier in CEF. It's a pure evil work with DOM snapshots.

Comment: Thanks for the new link, I found dom manipulation to be great! What about it you did not like? If you have to do loads of manipulation you can just write a javascript file with JQUERY and insert all of that in 1 go.

Comment: Mostly those snapshots. You're not working with the *living* site elements, but the DOM visitor takes a snapshot of the site, which limits you quite much (thus I would never compare it with MSHTML).

Comment: @TLama snapshots seem to be good solution to have a consistent DOM tree as opposed to a living one, which does not support some kind of "transacted" read (and write). Reading from a living DOM sounds like having a moving target.